# delete JS Object attributes based on a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have certain objects that I have to delete certain properties ie:

```
objA = { firstAttrA: 'fooA', secondAttrA: 'barA' }
objB = { firstAttrB: 'fooB', secondAttrB: 'barB' }
```

I want to pass these objects in a function that will delete the firstAttrA and firstAttrB based on the following properties file:

```
{
    "objA":"firstAttrA",
    "objB":"firstAttrB"
}
```

The method needs to be robust, I need to avoid excessive looping and anything that will affect performance since the amount of objects that will essentially be passed is great and their properties numerous.

Essentially i suppose I need to do a `delete objA.firstAttrA; delete objB.firstAttrB;` but driven by a JSON properties file.

Comment: Fantastic, it's good to have a goal. However, Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, we expect you to have taken a stab at solving the problem for yourself first and to demonstrate that effort in the question (if you have code, even if it doesn't work, that's better than nothing). This is, currently, a very broad problem, so you'll need to narrow it down to the specific part that you're struggling with. If you have absolutely no idea where to start that's OK too, you just need to say that.

Answer (score 0):

Well if defined in the global scope then your method would look like this:

```
var objRef = {
    "objA":"firstAttrA",
    "objB":"firstAttrB"
};
for (var item in objRef) {
    if (window.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        if (window[item].hasOwnProperty(objRef[item])) {
            delete window[item][objRef[item]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious: Why `if (window[item].hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: @zeroflagL To avoid calling delete on non-existent properties. Also if the property is defined in the prototype then it shouldn't be deleted.